# Can I connect wireless headphones to Xbox One S?

Tags: xbox-one

Is it possible to connect normal wireless Bluetooth headphones to an Xbox One S without buying any adapters?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible, the bluetooth is just to connect the controller to a PC.

https://forums.xbox.com/en-US/thread/EA3A74E2-280C-4B3D-80F2-1AF4C7BC8F87